# Can I recover MEW private key with password?

Tags: myetherwallet, private-key

I feel desperate. I lost my private key and keystore file. Are my tokens stuck in the wallet forever?

Can I recover the private key only with password? Or can any hard wallet be connected with the wallet with password?

Comment: Do you already have a hard wallet that you used to store your Ether?

Comment: No, but I’m willing to buy it if it is possible to connect it with my mew by using the password..

Answer (score 0):

You can't recover your privateKey with just a password, however, if you still have the 12-word mnemonic seed phrase, you can recover all the associated metamask accounts/your vault, if not, there's not much to do for you. You could however give this approach a chance, hope you figure it out!
 This is a link for a Web UI for decrypting MetaMask local storage
https://github.com/MetaMask/vault-decryptor